# Can't upload image by POST method from url. Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, request

I can't send an image object in multipart/form-data format without writing and reading it on the disk. This method does not work:

```
    response = requests.get(offer['picture'])
    if not response.ok:
        print('Error!', response)
        continue
    image = response.content
    response = requests.post(upload_url, files={'file': image})
```

API thinks that image is too small. But this method works:

```
    response = requests.get(offer['picture'])
    if not response.ok:
        print('Error!', response)
        continue
    image = response.content
    with open('test.jpg', 'wb') as file:
        file.write(image)
    response = requests.post(upload_url, files={'file': open('test.jpg', 'rb')})
```

How can I upload image without writing it on the disk?

Comment: Try giving it a file name?. response = requests.post(upload_url, files= {'file' : ('test.jpg', image)})

Comment: Yes, it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working code:

```
response = requests.get(offer['picture'])
if not response.ok:
    print('Error!', response)
    continue
image = response.content
response = requests.post(upload_url, files={'file': ('image.jpg', image)})
```